# How do I migrate user passwords?

Tags: 8, users, migrations

I have refactored an old Drupal 6 site to Drupal 8 and my only problem is, i migrated the users but the password is incorrect. i know that the password in Drupal 6 is a MD5 hash, but i cannot find a solution to convert this password, that Drupal 8 can read it.

Is there any solution for the password migration yet? can i give the MD5 hash a prefix inside of the database to make it readable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User and user password migration is part of the `Migrate` and `Migrate Drupal` modules that come with Drupal 8 and that can easily be accessed using the `Migration Drupal UI`.

One word of warning though, from the guide on [Upgrading using the migration user interface](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/upgrade/upgrade-using-the-migration-user-interface):

> Due to password encryption, user accounts take particularly long to
>   import.

Comment: The UI is actually just the UI, it's the migrations themself that deal with this. Basically, it is the same logic as the Drupal 7 upgrade path, the md5 hashes are hashed again using the new API, and when such a user tries to log in, we first hash the password with md5(), and then again, compare it, if it matches, we generate a new hash that doesn't rely on md5 and persist that.

Answer (score 5):

Security wise it would make sense to import them in Drupal and then use the [Mass Password Reset module](https://www.drupal.org/project/mass_pwreset) to reset all passwords.

Answer (score 0):

See [Migrating MD5 hashed passwords](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-destination-plugins-examples/migrating-users#md5)

There is also a D6 migration example in `/core/modules/user/migration_templates/d6_user.yml`:

```
id: d6_user
label: User accounts
migration_tags:
  - Drupal 6
source:
  plugin: d6_user
process:
  ...
  pass: pass
  ...
...
destination:
  plugin: entity:user
  md5_passwords: true
...
```

Key solution here to correctly migrate the passwords is to use the `md5_passwords: true` option for the destination user entity. So make sure you include that option in your user migration config.